# Ruby on Rails Devise master password

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm trying to implement the master password feature for Devise with my User model but after following the [wiki article](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Configure-a-master-password) I'm getting the following error when trying to start my rails server:

```html
/Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:324:in `Integer': can't convert Hash into Integer (TypeError)
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:324:in `sanitize_limit'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:856:in `build_arel'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/query_methods.rb:842:in `arel'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:611:in `exec_queries'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:493:in `load'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation.rb:238:in `to_a'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:474:in `find_nth_with_limit'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/relation/finder_methods.rb:130:in `first'
 from /Users/godzilla/.rbenv/versions/2.3.0/lib/ruby/gems/2.3.0/gems/activerecord-4.1.7/lib/active_record/querying.rb:3:in `first'
 from /Users/godzilla/Documents/Coding/app-api/app/models/user.rb:142:in `<class:User>'
 from /Users/godzilla/Documents/Coding/app-api/app/models/user.rb:1:in `<top (required)>'
```

So, it indicates there is an error on line 142 in my User model.  For the time being, I just cut and pasted the code straight from the wiki to get the implementation going.

**models/user.rb**

```html
def valid_password?(password)
  return true if valid_master_password?(password)
  super
end

DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL = 'auser@mydomain.com' 
DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.first(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)
DEFAULT_ENCRYPTED_MASTER_PASSWORD = DEFAULT_MASTER_USER.try(:encrypted_password)

def valid_master_password?(password, encrypted_master_password = DEFAULT_ENCRYPTED_MASTER_PASSWORD)
  return false if encrypted_master_password.blank?
  bcrypt_salt = ::BCrypt::Password.new(encrypted_master_password).salt
  bcrypt_password_hash = ::BCrypt::Engine.hash_secret("#{password}#{self.class.pepper}", bcrypt_salt)
  Devise.secure_compare(bcrypt_password_hash, encrypted_master_password)
end
```

Is there something else that I need to do to get this working?  Based on what Devise says, it should pretty much be a cookie-cutter implementation.

Comment: Do reformat your question's code.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up changing:

`DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.first(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)`

to

`DEFAULT_MASTER_USER = self.find_by(email: DEFAULT_MASTER_USER_EMAIL)`

Since it's trying to do the lookup by the email address, not the `id`.  Works now.